# user_save() returns FALSE

Tags: users

I am trying to use user_save api. i have passed the following object ($user)

```
object(stdClass)#30 (6) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(12) "user_name"
  ["mail"]=>
  string(22) "myemail@gmail.com"
  ["pass"]=>
  int(1311514302)
  ["created"]=>
  int(1311514302)
  ["status"]=>
  int(1)
  ["roles"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "OauthUsers"
  }
}
```

I have used the following function:

```
$user = new stdClass();
$user->name = $userdata['name'];
$user->mail = $userdata['email'];
$user->pass = time();
$user->created = time();
$user->status = 1;
$user->roles = array('OauthUsers');
user_save($user);
```

I have tried to drop the "roles" property as well, but in all the cases user_save() returns `FALSE`.

Do you have any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATED:

If you are going to create new users using `user_save()` then follow the following syntax.

```
$user = array(
   'name' => $userdata['name'],
   'mail' => $userdata['mail'],
   'init' => $userdata['mail'],
   'pass' => user_password(8),
);
```

Now call the function `user_save()` and pass the user info as second arg.

```
$account = user_save(null, $user);
if($account){
     _user_mail_notify('register_admin_created', $account);
}
```

To update values for already saved user.

```
$account = user_load(array('uid' => $userdata['uid']));
$updates = array(
    'pass' => user_password(),
    'name' => 'new_name',
    'roles' => array(
        <rid> => '<role title>';
    ),
);

user_save($account, $updates);
```

Comment: what about the role?? i need the added user to have specific role which is "OauthUsers"??

Comment: $user = user_save($user, array('roles' => array('3' => 'special role')));